# include Rmarkdown pdf output code into a seperate latex theisis tex file

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, tex

I am trying to write a `report.tex` theists using `TexMAKER`,and I need to include a lot of r,
So I run my chunk code file with this preamble in `Rmarkdow`

```
title: "rcode"
author: ".."
date: "..."
output:
  
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
    fig_caption: yes
  html_document: default
```

then include the `rcode.pdf` output file in my original `report.tex` file using the command `\includepdf[]{rcode.pdf}`
this method is not so good because the page numbering in my `report.pdf` gets mixed up with the numbering of the `Rmardown` pdf output `rcode.pdf`,
So I am wondering if there is a new way to extract the `rcode.tex` code then include it in my `report.tex` file ?
Or is the better way just to start wring all of the theisis report in the `rmardown` file with out having any Latex complications ?
thanks for the help

Comment: 1) you can add `keep_tex: true` to your header and then copy from the resulting .tex document to your thesis 2) produce `rcode.pdf` without page numbers and let the pdfpages package take care of adding the correct numbering 3) you could use tools like knitr etc to directly use r in your document https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr 4) maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/includernw

Comment: I will add another issue in the post , the issue of figures not showing up in my report file

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question, including a compilable [mre]

Comment: thanks, I asked the question in another post